# ASP.Net SessionID keep retain while open new browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session

I have  a Javascript Expand/collapse Menu . When open New Window a session cookie is created to maintain the states of the menu(i.e, Expanded or Collapse).

1.If we open some node of menu.It maitain their states in   cookie.

2.But when we open new browser window, then no new session made ,it get the pervious session,due to this, Menu still showes expanded.

3.But if we close all the browser then it is working fine,it creates new session in this case.

I need to open a second browser window or tab, but it must have a different SessionID. Opening the new browser window from an ASP.NET page is easy, but then it shares the same cookie and thus SessionID with the original. 
How can I do this?

Thanks for help,

Jaydeep

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you should not use session id for the logic of displaying menus in your form. Instead of this you can just use hidden field value or querystring value.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to open a second browser window or tab, but it must have a different SessionID

Sorry but this is impossible to achieve. That's how browsers work and you have no control over this behavior. Take for example gmail: you log into your account and then open another browser tab/window and you will still be logged in because cookies are shared between tabs/windows.

So you should use some other storage mechanism like url ids or hidden fields, and not cookies.

Answer (score 0):

To get possibility to use different sessions in different browser tabs, You can use cookieless sessions. You can read about in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx).